# Extract values from a given format with limited String Methods and no control structures

Tags: java, string, class

For my java program I basically have to parse user input in this syntax: lastName, firstName middleName *with* the **comma**.

This is normally easy but I have to use the methods taught in my beginner class such as: `indexOf`, `substring`, and `parseInt` along with all primitive data types and no if else statements. I can't use `length()`, or use one number instead of two. only the version of `substring` with two arguments can be used;
Thanks all!

Edit: the following code i have is what i got so far. All i need to do is convert the syntax: Last, First Middle to First Middle Last without the comma.

```
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("\fEnter your name in this syntax: Last, First Middle");
       String inputGet = input.nextLine();

       int comma = inputGet.indexOf(",");
       System.out.println(comma);
       String lastNameGet = inputGet.substring(0,comma);
       System.out.println(lastNameGet);
       System.out.println(inputGet);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: so you have used the comma, that separates the last and first names. what could you look for as the limit between first and middle name?

Comment: I could use the space, but the problem with that is there is a space after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the entire solution, but if you are looking for a way to get the length of the string, try this:

```
String inputGet= ...
int lengthOfInput = (inputGet+"[Not part of anybody's name]").indexOf("[Not part of anybody's name]")-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("\fEnter your name in this syntax: Last, First Middle");
       String inputGet = input.nextLine();

       int comma = inputGet.indexOf(",");
       String lastNameGet = " " + inputGet.substring(0,comma);
       System.out.println(inputGet.substring(comma+2,inputGet.lastIndexOf("")) + lastNameGet);
```

If using `lastIndexOf` is forbidden as well, then you can take advantage of this modified version of Flight's length method, and do:

```
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("\fEnter your name in this syntax: Last, First Middle");
       String inputGet = input.nextLine();

       int comma = inputGet.indexOf(",");
       String lastNameGet = " " + inputGet.substring(0,comma);
       int lengthOfInput = (inputGet+"[Not part of anybody's name]").indexOf("[Not part of anybody's name]");
       System.out.println(inputGet.substring(comma+2,lengthOfInput) + lastNameGet);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i figured out my problem and solved my teacher's homework. If it wasn't for you guy's health i would be stuck. Thanks!